# converting gstreamer0.10 pipeline to gstreamer1.0

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-0.10, gstreamer-1.0

Hello I need to convert a gstreamer0.10 pipeline to a gstreamer1.0 pipeline but don't know much about gstreamer in general.

My 0.10 pipeline is looking like this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src num-buffers=2 device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=3072,height=2048,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc! multifilesink location=test.jpg
```

I tried to convert it like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src num-buffers=2 device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=3072,height=2048,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=test.jpg
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to run the pipeline:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.473942184
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Which version of gstreamer? This works for me (v 1.9):
gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=2 ! video/x-raw, width=1024,height=768,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=test%03d.jpg

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 Version 1.2.4 is my version